# HighChart graphics with node js and react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, highcharts

I'm using library highChart https://www.highcharts.com/ for statistics graphs and i wanna  know if there's the possibility to create data different in different  periods for exemple I have series like that :

```
Categories : [
                '2021-01-01',
                '2021-01-02',
                '2021-01-03',
                '2021-01-04',
                '2021-01-05',
                '2021-01-06',
                '2021-01-07',
                '2021-01-08',
                '2021-01-09',
                '2021-01-10',
                '2021-01-11',
                '2021-01-12',
                '2021-01-13',
                '2021-01-14',
                '2021-01-15',
                '2021-01-16',
                '2021-01-17',
                '2021-01-18',
                '2021-01-19',
                '2021-01-20',
                '2021-01-21',
                '2021-01-22',
                '2021-01-23',
                '2021-01-24',
                '2021-01-25',
                '2021-01-26',
                '2021-01-27',
                '2021-01-28',
                '2021-01-29',
                '2021-01-30',
             ]
series : [
{
    name : 'serie 1',
    data : [
                {x : '2021-01-05' , s : 5},
                {x : '2021-01-10' , s : 20},
                {x : '2021-01-11' , s : 40},
                {x : '2021-01-15' , s : 80},
                {x : '2021-01-30' , s : 20},

           ]
}

] 


i wanna the x values in the graphic get the period in categories and get the x value from series to compare if the x value in series exist then get s value in the series else put 0 
How i can do that in highChart
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented a logic that parsed data into a wanted format. Take a look at this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hrasqo92/

```
const parsedData = categories.map(category => {
  const dataPoint = baseData.filter(data => data.x === category);
  if (dataPoint.length) {
    return [category, dataPoint[0].y]
  } else {
    return [category, 0]
  }
})
```